# How do I get MySQL query results from component menu item in Joomla and refine with a foreach where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, components, where-clause

I have Custom component J 2.5. In menu of this component also I have sql field:

```
<field
    name="title"
    type="sql"
    default="10"
    label="აირჩიეთ კატეგორია"
    multiple="multiple"
    query="SELECT id AS value, title FROM #__deals_categories"
/>
```

I am geting data from the function and storing it in the `$category` array:

```
$dealsparam = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$category = $dealsparam->get(title, 10);
```

Output for $category is array:

```
Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 23 [2] => 33 [3] => 41 [4] => 49 )
```

These are category ids from the database. 
Also, I have a function to get content from these categories. All is ok when I have one category id, but when I have many category ids ex: 2, 4, 5, etc., I cannot get data from mysql. I try to foreach a where clause, but there is some error I could not understand.

In the following, I am trying to foreach a where clause and get data from many different categories:

```
if ($category) {
    print_r ($category);
    foreach ($category as $cat){
        $query->where('d.category_id = ' . (int) $cat);
        echo $cat.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `IN` instead of `=` condition -

```
$category = (array) $category;
jimport('joomla.utilities.arrayhelper');
JArrayHelper::toInteger($category);
if(!empty($category)){
    $query->where('d.category_id IN(' . implode(',', $category) . ')');
}
```

Comment: `<?php
// $category output is 23 when I echo $category; and there is no records
->where('d.category_id = ' . (int) $category)
// also this method not work
->where('d.category_id = ' . $category)
// but this method works 
->where('d.category_id = 23')
?>`

Comment: @Gocha : Not sure what's wrong but might be updated code will help.

Comment: @Gocha: Create another question for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with your '$query->where' statement, is to add 'AND' SQL conditions to the query. So, if an item belongs to only one category, no item will match.
You have two choices:
1- Stated by Irfan: use IN(category1, category2, ...)
2- Use 'OR' to make up the query:

```
(d.category_id = category1) OR (d.category_id = category2) ...
```